# Magento UPS Shipping Weird Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, ups

I want to ask something.. 
Do you ever use UPS Shipping module in magento?
I have weird case.. If I set shipping settings from "United States", the shipping module is working well..

But, If I set it from indonesia ( I already check the zip code fromups.com/ctc ), it's shows me nothing.. And I'll check it from ups.com/ctc , it shows me result..
So, anyone know about this problem?
Thanks

Comment: are you selecting proper shipping method and address which is supported from indonesia ?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is, that the built in ups module is only working for us adresses ... at least I did not get it running for UK adresses.

You can investigate the reason by setting:

```
System->Configuraton->Shipping Methods->UPS->Debug = Yes.
```

For every communication with the ups server you will find an entry in folder

`/var/www/yourmagentoshop/var/log/shipping_ups.log` file.

Logfile contains the request Array with data like

```
 ...
 [22_destCountry] => GB
 ...
```

and gets a result from the ups server

```
[result] => UPSOnLine5%Unsupported country specified%6920
```

Magento uses 2 character country codes, as the ups web site interface expects 3 character country codes.

I now use the `Webshopapps Matrix Rates` free extension and setup weight and country dependent table rates for ups shipping.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is not related to `ISO` codes for countries.

The `UPS` carrier (based on cgi) allows to ship only if origin country is `USA`, your origin country is `Indonesia`, that's why you get this error. But you can use `UPS XML` type instead.

Comment: Negotiated rate does not display, instead of showing standard rates, could you pls help @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/213793/57334