# Integrated UPS option for US only?

Tags: ups, germany

I want to use integrated UPS as delivery option in Germany, but always get "This shipping method is currently unavailable" in the cart.

Is that integrated UPS option meant for US only? ([Magento UPS Shipping Weird Problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54200/magento-ups-shipping-weird-problem))

Is there some alternative plugin that does the same? I wan't to calculate the shipping costs based on the delivery country.

Comment: apply on Ship to Specific Countries options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: I got it working on my German Magento Shop.
The issue wasn't that it just works with US markets (what I read in another forum).
The issue just was that my test products weren't configured properly.
So some products were 200kg in weight..and the limit was set to 150kg in the UPS settings.

Comment: You still won't be able to use functions like tracking and printing lables as they are for US market.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Yes. All the carriers, like DHL, UPS and Fedex in Mage Core are for the US market and their respective APIs.

Thats why DHL is not working out of the box too.