# UPS Error : Negotiated Price Not showing instead of showing Standard Price?

Tags: magento-1.9, ups

I have configured UPS for my site, at checkout page UPS showing standard charges not showing my Negotiated Charges, how can configure to display my Negotiated Charges.

Comment: Its been over a year since you asked this questions. Have you solved this issue?